# What should a YouTube video to promote LLSE contain?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, video

I have mentioned this before, but I should get around to doing it in the next two weeks: making a YouTube video to promote our site. This would by a screencast with a voice over. What should this video cover and in what order? I am thinking of the following:

1. What LLSE is, i.e. a question and answer site about learning and teaching languages.
2. How asking questions works.
3. How answering questions works.
4. The reps system.
5. What types of questions are on topic and what types of questions are off topic.

Anything else?

I will release this video under a CC-BY-SA licence (Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike), the same licence that is used for all StackExchange content.

Comment: Is this a _promotional_ video or an _instructional_ video? Is it like a video advertisement or a guide on how to use the site?

Comment: @Hatchet Well, my current concept is an instructional video to promote the site. However, if anyone posts an idea for a promotional video that is not instructional I will also consider it (at least if it doesn't require any video editing wizardry).

Answer (score 2):

I think that's a great idea. One thing I'd suggest is perhaps submitting a preliminary idea of what a script for the video might look like as a community wiki meta post, so that you can receive some modifications or improvements to the script. Once the video is published, I think we should also add it to our help center as a quick "What is LL?" explanatory video for new visitors to our site. I think we could actually go ahead and maybe post such a video on related meta StackExchange sites, like EL&U or ELL.

In terms of the actual content of the video, I would suggest adding a brief summary of what meta is and how to use it, perhaps after you've covered everything else.

Comment: The hard part will be getting the voiceovers since we're not like capable of recording at one another's house...